# ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute: p_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails

after I run

> bundle exec rake db:seed

The titled error will show.
Could anyone has a look at my RoR code? I've not sure where is the issue.
my

> product.rb

file

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_primary_key :p_id
  attr_accessible :p_id, :name, :category, :description, :price
end
```

> schema.rb

```
#
# It's strongly recommended to check this file into your version control system.

ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20111119180638) do

  create_table "products", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "p_id"
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "category"
    t.text     "description"
    t.string   "price"
    t.datetime "created_at",  :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  :null => false
  end
end
```

> create_products.rb

```
class CreateProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table :products, {:id => false} do |t|
      t.string :p_id
      t.string :name
      t.string :category
      t.text :description
      t.string :price
      # Add fields that let Rails automatically keep track
      # of when products are added or modified:
      t.timestamps
    end
        execute "ALTER TABLE products ADD PRIMARY KEY (p_id);"
  end

  def down
    drop_table :products
  end
end
```

Comment: Shouldn't `p_id` be a Integer type column?

Comment: No, p_id is imported from csv file and it is a string

Comment: You don't need the attr_accessible list as activerecord creates this methods by itself.

Comment: What's the backtrace? Have you verified that the table actually has a p_id column?

Answer (score 0):

primery_key method is expecting an string:

```
self.primary_key 'p_id'
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/PrimaryKey/ClassMethods.html#method-i-primary_key-3D